# Import Error Python (linux)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, importerror

I've installed *django rest framework* using `pip install djangorestframework`. While running Django's development server via:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I am getting below error:

```
ImportError at / No module named 'django.utils.six.moves.http_client';
   'django.utils.six.moves' is not a package 
Request Method: GET 
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Django Version: 1.5 
Exception Type: ImportError 
Exception Value:     No module named 'django.utils.six.moves.http_client';

'django.utils.six.moves' is not a package Exception Location:
    /home/sony/environments/djangular/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py in <module>,
line 11 Python Executable:
/home/sony/environments/djangular/bin/python3 
Python Version: 3.4.3 
Python Path:     ['/home/sony/environments/djangular/djangular',  
'/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',  
'/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
'/home/sony/environments/djangular/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Django version is too old to use with current Django REST framework and Python 3.4.  That's an unsupported configuration.

Also, [`djangular`](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular) [requires Python 2.7](https://github.com/appliedsec/djangular#requirements), according to the github landing page.